# MySQL: Update based on two columns of inner join

Tags: mysql

I have `table_a` and `a_audit`. `table_a` has columns `id`, `client_id`, `originating_client_id`. `a_audit` has the same columns; it is used to track the changes to `table_a`.

I have this select query to get all rows from `table_a` where client_id IS NULL, originating_client_id IS NULL and there is a row in the audit table that contains a client_id:

```
select t.id,
       t.client_id,
       t.originating_client_id,
       a.client_id
from table_a t
inner join a_audit a
  on a.id = t.id
where t.client_id is null
  and t.originating_client_id is null
  and a.client_id is not null
group by ur.user_role_id /* not necessary? */
```

[image: select query]

What I want to do is: for each row in `table_a` where `client_id IS NULL` and `originating_client_id IS NULL`, find the first row in `a_audit` that has the same `id` and has a `client_id`, then set `table_a.originating_client_id` = `client_id` from that row of `a_audit`

[image: intent]

Comment: What do you mean by the first row in a_audit table? If there will be two rows with the same id and client_id not null, whats then?

Comment: @lypskee - I want the first row because the client_id might have been changed, but the first one is the original (aka originating) client_id.

Comment: @lypskee - the audit table does contain a timestamp column. For the sake of this post, we can call it `a_audit.updated_on`

Comment: See [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get all the rows of `a_audit` with the minimum `updated_on` for each `id` and `client_id` not `null` and join to `table_a`:

```
update table_a t inner join (
  select a.* from  a_audit a
  where a.client_id is not null
  and not exists (
    select 1 from a_audit
    where id = a.id and updated_on < a.updated_on
  )  
) a on a.id = t.id
set t.originating_client_id = a.client_id
where t.client_id is null and t.originating_client_id is null
```

Comment: on the first select, why not do `order by updated_on desc limit 1`?

Comment: limit 1 returns only 1 row. Why should I use it? You need all the rows from a_audit with client_id not null and with the minimum updated_on for each id.

Comment: I didn't fully understand what the `and not exists` statement was doing. that's pretty clever. thanks!